# Save powerpoint presentation as as a pdf in vba

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint

I have looked at a lot of answers to this question but can't figure out what I have done wrong.  I am trying to create a pdf file.  I get my data from an excel file and copy it into powerpoint.  I then try to save as pdf but it keeps giving me an error (object required) at the saving pdf section of the macro (see below).  I tried changing it multiple times but still can't get it to work.  Have attached code below.  After I fix this problem, I need to be able to change the size of the object I pasted in - how do I do that.

```
Sub CreatePDFfiles_4()


Dim PPapp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim first_file As Boolean
Dim investorname As String
Dim path As String


Sheets("printing").Select
Range("g2").Select
file1 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("g3").Select
path = ActiveCell.Value
Range("g8").Select
investorname = ActiveCell.Value
Range("i8").Select
cor_file_name = ActiveCell.Value
DestinationPPT = "C:\Users\name\Documents\company\Investment Model\printing macro\template.pptx"


While investorname <> "end"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    print_data = ActiveCell.Value
    If print_data = "Yes" Then

        ' Initialize PowerPoint Object Library
        Set PPapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
        PPapp.Visible = True

        ' Open presentation
        Set PPPres = PPapp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

        'Copy excel file data
        Windows(file1).Activate
        Sheets(investorname).Select
        Range("b1:r46").Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste into existing powerpoint template slide that is open
        PPPres.slides(1).Shapes.Paste

        'Save as pdf
        PPPres.ExportAsFixedFormat ActivePresentation.path & "\" & cor_file_name & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint



        PPapp.Quit
        Set PPapp = Nothing
```

Comment: Unless you have a reference to the Powerpoint library, you will need to give values to all the constants such as `ppFixedFormatTypePDF`.  Put `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module and it will complain about anything that isn't defined.

Comment: Re "After I fix this problem ..." - After the current issue is fixed, raise another question.  Trying to solve multiple issues in one questions just ends up getting the question closed as "too broad".

Comment: I have not coded much .  I tried putting it in after Sub CreatePDFfiles_4() and it woudn't take it.  Where should I put Option Explicit?

Comment: `Option Explicit` should be the **first** line of your code module - i.e. before any other line of code.  Go to the very top of the code (possibly your `Sub` statement, possibly something else), insert a line **before** it, enter `Option Explicit`.

Comment: Other than those PPT constants, you should also have issue with `ActivePresentation` inside Excel VBA. Where does `cor_file_name` come from? You don't seem to have pasted all the code for that Sub?

Comment: I figured out where to put Option Explicit but how should I define ppFIxed FormatType PDF.  I tried string and it didn't work

Comment: I added cor_file_name as string and used  PPPres.ExportAsFixedFormat invpath & cor_file_name & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint but that didn't work and tried replacing PPPres with ACtivePresentation and that didn't work

Comment: Define `ppFixedFormatTypePDF` as a `Long` with a value of `2`. `ppFixedFormatIntentPrint` also is meant to have a value of `2`. (You can find the values of the constants by opening PowerPoint, going into the VBE, going to Object Browser, and searching for them.)  If you don't want to write the `Const ppFixedFormatTypePDF As Long = 2`, etc, statements you could just write the line as `PPPres.ExportAsFixedFormat PPPres.path & "\" & cor_file_name & ".pdf", 2, 2`.  (But I would recommend you create the constants.)

Comment: @PatricK The first time I read the code I couldn't see `cor_file_name` either.  It's not declared, so was defaulting to a `Variant/String` variable, but it is actually set - `cor_file_name = ActiveCell.Value`.

Comment: Now I get a type mismatch on the line.  I defined the two constants are you suggested.  Is the problem the PPPres as the object?  thank you for all your help - clearly in over my head!

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure this out .  STill get the type mismatch error on the

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure this out.  I still get the type mistmatch error on PPPres.ExportAsFixedFormat PPPres.path & "\" & cor_file_name & ".pdf", 2, 2

Comment: I even got rid of the filename reference to make sure it wasn't that and still got the type mismatch error.     PPPres.ExportAsFixedFormat PPPres.path & "\" & "test.pdf", 2, 2

Answer (score 4):

None of that worked for me. it was as simple as:

```
file_name = (path and name of the file you want to open)
Path = (where you want to save it)
PdfFileNm = (name of the file)

Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set Pres = PPT.presentations.Open(file_name)
PPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs Path & PdfFileNm & ".pdf", 32
```

Comment: Just as a note here: I assume the 32 is the value of the ppSaveAsPDF flag / key.