Powerpoint VBA to save slide as PDF with "Source formatting" fails
I'm able to run a macro that save each slide of a presentation as a separate pdf file, and are named using a text box within that slide.
The blocker I face is when I keep source formatting while creating/pasting the new slide. When do this, the saving to pdf no longer works. It throws the below error
Run time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
Presentation (unknown member) : The slides  have selected to print longer exist. 
Please make another selection.

Below is the full code.

Sub SplitSlidesIntoSeparateFilesv4()
    Dim SourcePres As Presentation
    Dim NewPres As Presentation
    Dim SourceSlide As Slide
    Dim FilePaath As String
    Dim FileName As String

    ' Set the source presentation
    Set SourcePres = ActivePresentation

    ' Choose the folder to save the files
    FilePath = InputBox("Enter the full path where you want to save the files:", "File Path")
    If FilePath = "" Then Exit Sub ' Exit if no path is provided
    
    ' The shape in the slide that contains the text to name the converted file .
    shapeName = "Rectangle 35"

    ' Loop through each slide in the presentation
    For Each SourceSlide In SourcePres.Slides
        ' Create a new presentation
        Set NewPres = Presentations.Add
        ' Copy the slide
        SourceSlide.Copy
        ' Paste the slide into the new presentation. <<< Introduction of this causes the error >>>
        NewPres.Windows(1).Activate
        NewPres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
        
        ' Previous code, which works fine is below.  It does not do source formatting, but saving as pdf works fine.
        ' NewPres.Slides.Paste
        
        ' Save the new presentation
        
        For Each Shape In SourceSlide.Shapes
            ' Check if the shapes name matches the specified name
            If Shape.Name = shapeName Then
                FileName = FilePath & "\" & "Slide_" & Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & ".pdf"
                NewPres.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Path:=FileName, _
                FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, _
                Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, _
                FrameSlides:=msoTrue, _
                HandoutOrder:=ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst, _
                OutputType:=ppPrintOutputSlides, _
                PrintHiddenSlides:=msoCTrue, _
                PrintRange:=Nothing, _
                RangeType:=ppPrintAll, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                DocStructureTags:=True, _
                BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
                UseISO19005_1:=False
                
            End If
        Next Shape
    Next SourceSlide
End Sub
    



Before NewPres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting") select the slide and wait for it to finish selection, which looks to take some time, using something like: Dim i as long For i = 1 To 5000: DoEvents: Next. After this waiting time .ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting") should work.

@FaneDuru NewPres.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting") already works when saving each slide as a PPT. Its when save each file as PDF that this error pops up. Although please note, i AM able to save each slide as PDF when i use the normal paste option

Rather than copy/pasting slides, it will be more reliable to do one of two things:
Set .PrintRange to just the slide you want to save (see the comment from @swapnil at the bottom of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445063/save-powerpoint-presentation-as-as-a-pdf-in-vba ) OR once per slide, save the presentation to a temp file, then delete from it all of the slides BUT the one you want to export.

@SteveRindsberg I chose your option 1. That means, I do not need a target presentation, and also I remove the Copy and Paste sections. I then loop through each slide and give the Print options and then do the Export command. Is that right? I tried this, although i get silly errors Object Variable or With block variable not set.

On what line/lines do you get this error?

@SteveRindsberg For Each SourceSlide In SourcePres.Slides. Has it got something to do with the new line Set pr = SourcePres.PrintOptions.Ranges.Add(Start:=SourceSlide.SlideNumber, End:=SourceSlide.SlideNumber) that i added ?

Start by adding Option Explicit at the very top of the module containing this sub, then keep compiling until it stops throwing compile errors.  At the very least, you'll need to add     Dim FilePath As String (spell it correctly!), Dim FileName As String,     Dim ShapeName As String, and Dim oSh As Shape, then change each instance of Shape used as a variable to oSh.
